# Loading a jPlaton unit

Tags: tomcat, jplaton

I am writing a new unit on the jPlaton platform, but I have a problem in the page.xml and my unit cannot be successfully loaded. I want the page.xml to have just an HTML_presenter element. I have declared it like this:

```
    <p_HTMLPresenter
        width="1"
        height="1"
        panel="MainPanel"
        parameters="defaultAction=p_defaultPresenterDataAction"
        x_position="0"
        y_position="0"
    ></p_HTMLPresenter>
```

In the code.xml I have set and initialized the defaultPresenterDataAction. I have also declared it in the data.xml. defaultPresenterDataAction calls a procedure named home (p_home) which is also declared in code.xml. And as always a setProperties procedure is present.

When I try to open the unit, PlatonScript throws the following error in the Tomcat cosnole:

```
Component out of table!p_HTMLPresenter
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After hours and hours I figured it out. I had to set

```
<p_setProperties
    action_type="after_unit_open"
></p_setProperties>
```

in the PROPERTIES section of the code.xml